# On the uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In the derivation of the Uncertainty principle, I am facing a problem in understanding how

$\Delta E=\frac{2p\Delta p}{2m}$

is it $\Delta p^2 = p\Delta p + \Delta pp = 2p\Delta p$ or something else?

Please Explain. Thanks.

Comment: it seems like the differential of $E=p^2/2m$, and it not clear how this connects to the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Here I am referring to the derivation of uncertainty principle involving Energy and time

Comment: @AnujTanwar Can you put the whole derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No relation to the uncertainty principle, just Newton and the chain rule for derivatives.

assume $m$ is constant, $p = mv$, and $T = \frac{m}{2}v^2$

let $v = f(z)$ where $z$ is any parameter

$\frac{d}{dz} T = \frac{m}{2}(( \frac{d}{dz}v)v + v(\frac{d}{dz}v)) = mv\frac{d}{dz}v = p\frac{d}{dz}(p/m) = \frac{p\frac{d}{dz}p}{m}$

hence

$d T = \frac{pdp}{m}$

Going from *'differential element of'* to *'total change in'* is an approximation. It will work for $p \gg \Delta p$.